# Symfony 2 - UploadedFile, move method failed - Unable to create directory...

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, debian

I'm learning Symfony 2, and I have trouble with the class UploadedFile. 
I want to handle file uploading in my projet so I learned thanks to the official documentation : [How to handle File Uploads with Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html)

It works pretty good. However, it works just in local. I use MAMP for testing my project.

I tried to put my project in Debian 6 server. The Symfony app works, but the upload file doesn't work. 
When I move the file with the method move() ... I have this error :

```
Unable to create the &quot;/var/www/project/Symfony/src/project/Bundle/AlbumBundle/Entity/../../../../../web/images/postes_images&quot; directory (500 Internal Server Error)
```

As I told you, It works very well in local. If the folder postes_images doesn't exist, it supposed to create by itself. It works well in local...

This is my upload function:

```
public function upload($indexPoste, $indexPic)
{
    if (null === $this->file) {
       return;
    }

    $this->name = "poste_".$indexPoste."_pic_".$indexPic;
    $this->path = "poste_".$indexPoste."_pic_".$indexPic.".".$this->file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->path);

    $this->file = null;
}
```

Functions to get paths :

```
public function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__.'/../../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}

protected function getUploadDir()
{
    return 'images/postes_images';
}
```

The paths are correct, because it works very well in local. I'm wondering if it's not a problem of configuration of php ... 
I made some searchs, and I read that in move method, they call "mkdir" method to create the folder if it doesn't exist... If the mkdir call returns false, it returns the error that I put above.

If you have an idea how to resolve this issue please. I couldn't find anything.

Thanks

Comment: This is a user permission error on the server.  Your web user does not have sufficient privileges to create directories.  Make sure your web user has write permissions

Comment: Is it a configuration that I have to do in php, or apache ? 
Because the code symfony 2 is exactly the same than my local...
Where can I make this configuration for persmissions of web user please? :/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using Debian, your web user should be `www-data`.  So you need to ensure that this user has write permission to your `web/images` directory.  This may require root or sudo access, depending on your user permissions.  But run this command to give www-data access:

```
chown -R www-data /var/www/project/Symfony/web/images
```

This will allow the www-data user to own the directory and create further directories (assuming the owner has write permissions).  If you aren't up to speed on permissions, read [Debian Permission wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Permissions) to understand more.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I'm on a mac and I've set the permissions on 777: any ideas on how to solve? The move() method doesn't return any error, also wrapping it with a try statement.

Comment: @aerendir the web user on a mac is `_www`, so set the permissions for that user.

Comment: Perfect answer for Debian user !