# Symfony 2 simple file upload from cookbook error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm following the cookbook on uploading files in Symfony2: [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html)

I've made everything right and after submitting the form I'm getting the following error:

```
Unable to create the "/var/www/html/forum/src/Developer/Forum/ForumBundle/Entity/../../../../web/uploads/documents" directory
```

Found this solution on stackoverflow: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561094/symfony-2-uploadedfile-move-method-failed-unable-to-create-directory)

so I typed while being in my project folder:

```
chown -R www-data web/*
```

but it still doesn't work. Where could the problem be?

The error that could be helpful:

```
{
        if (!is_dir($directory)) {
            if (false === @mkdir($directory, 0777, true)) {
                throw new FileException(sprintf('Unable to create the "%s" directory', $directory));
            }
```

Comment: O.K. I've found the solution here: [solution][1]


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/19318/how-can-i-give-write-access-of-a-folder-to-all-users-in-linux

Comment: That's quite risky. You'd much better finding which user your apache is running under and giving write permissions only to that user....